# Why emulator error on android 7.0 and above?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, android-cursor

I'm working on an application that saves contacts in the .vcf file. I also get the following error when I run the emulator to test the application. Application is running on physical devices. But android 7.0 and above emulator also gives error. **(Caution: The emulator does not fail in Android 6.0)**

**cursor () seems to have an error in logcat. But it says "dlopen failed." Please review logcat. What could be the reason?**

I use GenyMotion as emulator.

Thanks in advance.

> My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button Backup_Button;

    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> vCard ;
    String vfile, vcardstring;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Backup_Button = findViewById(R.id.Backup_Button);

        vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".vcf";

        Backup_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getVcardString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clickeddddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void getVcardString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0){

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){

                get(cursor);
                Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i)); //(MainActivity.java:62) --- Caution: LogCat Error Line
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");

            Toast.makeText(this, "NO CONTACTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
    public void get(Cursor cursor){

        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        AssetFileDescriptor fd;

        try {

            fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            vcardstring = new String(buf);
            vCard.add(vcardstring);

            //Save contacts to storage

        } catch (Exception e1){

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> My LogCat:

```
2019-08-13 01:14:12.420 1811-2814/android.process.acore E/VCardComposer: Cursor#moveToNext() returned false
2019-08-13 01:14:12.453 2840-2840/com.androidcontactbackup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.androidcontactbackup, PID: 2840
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.androidcontactbackup.MainActivity.getVcardString(MainActivity.java:81)
        at com.androidcontactbackup.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:24)
        at com.androidcontactbackup.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: I think that you should have another stack trace above this one, as I think your `get()` call is throwing an exception. That would explain why `vCard()` has no element in it when you go to log it in `getVcardString()`. I do not know if there is a guarantee that you can get and read `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI`.

Comment: At first look your `ArrayList` is empty - `    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Comment: Shouldn't it also fail in android 6.0? The emulator works on Android 6.0. @CommonsWare

Comment: "Shouldn't it also fail in android 6.0?" -- as I wrote I do not know if there is a guarantee that you can get and read `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI`. Your code assumes that every single device will allow this for every possible contact. I do not feel that is a safe assumption, and your experience with Genymotion would appear to back that up. Only Genymotion can tell you whether this `Uri` would be available and readable on their Android 7.0 emulator, but you need to handle the case where it is not available and readable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line which throws the exception:

```
Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i)); //(MainActivity.java:62) --- Caution: LogCat Error Line
```

because you call `vCard.get(i)`, attempting to get the i'th item of vCard, however, this index is outside the bounds of the `ArrayList` called `vCard`. `vCard` is initialized like this:

```
vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So, the question is how many items `vCard` has. If it's empty, then any `i` would result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. If this is the case, then the `get` method of this class either never ran, or has thrown an exception before it had a chance to add an item to `vCard`. If the method never ran, then you need to find out why it's not being called. If in this version you have an exception thrown and catched here:

```
    try {

        fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
        fis.read(buf);
        vcardstring = new String(buf);
        vCard.add(vcardstring);

        //Save contacts to storage

    } catch (Exception e1){

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, you will need to log the size of `vCard` in both emulator versions. Find out what is this value in different versions and what's the cause of this. If you find the answer to this question you will know the solution as well.